# What are some standard approaches to preprocessing binary data in a classification problem?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, binary-data

In the context of a ninary classification problem if all the predictors (independent variables) are strictly binary {0,1} then is there a specific way to preprocess the data ? Assume there are no missing or noisy data points.

**More Info**: I am currently working on a project with gene expressions data. The predictors are completely binary and I am trying classify genes into two categories "cancerous" or "non cancerous". I have tried using logistic regession, svm (linear and rbf) and random forests as suggested in this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89914/building-a-classification-model-for-strictly-binary-data), however the auc for my application is about 0.65 for all the classifiers. I am trying to get the auc up. What approach should I be using ? I  hope there is a specific way to handle this data and not this is not a situation where the inter-class sepration is low.

Comment: How come gene expression is binary? Maybe you mean that your response (cancer / no cancer) is binary? Then logistic regression would be one of the many ways you can analizę your data. Or do you want to predict gene expression from binary predictors (cancer / no cancer)? In that case, you can use A NOVA.

Comment: I mean my predictors or independent variables are binary. The "gene expression" data here is the output of a graph model and not traditional methods such as microarray where the data is continuous.  So I would like to classify between non cancerous and cancerous genes in this context where all the predictors are binary valued.

Comment: Ah. I apologize. In that case – no, not as far as I can tell, you can directly plug in your binary predictors in the logistic model.

Comment: If all three models return similar results, then that score may be the best you can hope for with your data.