# How to assess feature usefulness?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, predictive-models, model-evaluation

I have a imbalanced dataset of 3k rows with 87:13 ratio of positive and negative classes. I am trying to do binary classification. Since my class proportion is skewed, I have optimize the decision threshold.

a) I have 3 independent features which are `feat_a`, `feat_b` and `feat_c`. While `feat_a` is studied heavily in literature and used in practice, we would like to see whether `feat_b` and `feat_c` add any value to our prediction model. So, I built a model (`model a`) with `feat_a`
using logistic regression. Now my objective is to build two more models as shown below

model b ~ `feat_a`, `feat_b` (will have two features)

model c ~ `feat_a`, `feat_b`, `feat_c` (will have three features)

Now my question is

a) How can I compare `model a`, `model b`, `model c`?

b) Since my dataset is imbalanced, I have to choose appropriate hyperparameters. Should this hyperparameters be same across all models because I want to compare them?

c) Should the decision threshold be same across all models? I know by default 0.5 is the threshold but since my dataset is imbalanced, it is important to optimize the threshold. Should I retain the same decision threshold across different models?

Can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Use logistic regression. That gives you  an estimated probability for membership, not a hard classification. Then, if you need a crisp decision at a later point, use a loss function based on real (say, economic) losses from wrong decisions.

There are many similar posts, for instance

- [How does logistic regression "elegantly" handle unbalanced classes?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403239/how-does-logistic-regression-elegantly-handle-unbalanced-classes)
- [Why isn't Logistic Regression called Logistic Classification?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127042/why-isnt-logistic-regression-called-logistic-classification)
- [Proper scoring rule when there is a decision to make (e.g. spam vs ham email)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/proper-scoring-rule-when-there-is-a-decision-to-make-e-g-spam-vs-ham-email)